# Minimax returning future moves, not the actual moves leading to a win

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Dots & Boxes AI with python, my problem is that when i increase the depth of minimax (for example: depth = 2) the best move that is returned to me is a future good move.

```
. _ . _ .
|       |
.   .   .
```

It would return something like this:

```
. _ . _ .
|       |
. _ .   .
```

There isn't a good move here for the AI, since it will always give the other player a box to complete. What my AI returns is for example [1, 0, -25, true] which means 1, 0 coordinates, a score -25 (Which means it completed a box but in this case it did not) and True meaning that the Horizontal line has been played (False would mean a vertical).
My guess is that it's just returning the future good move. Here's the code:

#### Evaluation

```
def evaluate(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n, is_maximizing):
    # linesX is the matrix of horizontal lines
    # linesY is the matrix of vertical lines
    i = 0
    j = 0
    is_x = True

    if winner(boxes) is True:
        score = 5000
    elif winner(boxes) is False:
        score = -5000
    else:
        # This returns coordinates to complete a box and score points
        can_complete = can_complete_box(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n)

        if can_complete and is_maximizing is True:
            i = can_complete[0][0]
            j = can_complete[0][1]
            is_x = can_complete[0][2]

            score = +25
        elif can_complete and is_maximizing is False:
            i = can_complete[0][0]
            j = can_complete[0][1]
            is_x = can_complete[0][2]

            score = -25
        else:
            move = choice(possible_moves(linesX, linesY))
            i = move[0]
            j = move[1]
            is_x = move[2]
            score = 0

    # i and j are coordinates,
    # score is the evaluation,
    # is_x says if it's linesX or linesY
    return i, j, score, is_x
```

#### Minimax

```
def minimax(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n, depth, is_maximizing):
    # Possible moves returns all the possible moves available
    if depth == 0 or len(possible_moves(linesX, linesY)) == 1:
        i, j, score, is_x = evaluate(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n, is_maximizing)
        return [i, j, score, is_x]

    # Maximizing players turn
    if is_maximizing:
        max_eval = -infinity
        best_move = None
        for move in possible_moves(linesX, linesY):
            i, j, is_x = move[0], move[1], move[2]

            # is_x tells me if it's a horizontal move or vertical

            if is_x:
                linesX[i][j] = True
            else:
                linesY[i][j] = True

            evaluation = minimax(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n, depth - 1, False)
            max_eval = max(max_eval, evaluation[2])

            # Reverses the moves that were played
            if is_x:
                linesX[i][j] = None
            else:
                linesY[i][j] = None

            if max_eval == evaluation[2]:
                best_move = [evaluation[0], evaluation[1], max_eval, evaluation[3]]

        return best_move
    else:
        min_eval = infinity
        best_move = None
        for move in possible_moves(linesX, linesY):
            i, j, is_x = move[0], move[1], move[2]

            if is_x:
                linesX[i][j] = False
            else:
                linesY[i][j] = False

            # evaluation returns [i, j, score, is_x]
            # i and j are coordinates of the move
            # score is the evaluation
            # is_x tells me if it's a horizontal or vertical move

            evaluation = minimax(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n, depth - 1, True)
            min_eval = min(min_eval, evaluation[2])

            if is_x:
                linesX[i][j] = None
            else:
                linesY[i][j] = None

            if min_eval == evaluation[2]:
                best_move = [evaluation[0], evaluation[1], min_eval, evaluation[3]]

        return best_move
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a long time so help would be very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: ```evaluation = minimax(boxes, linesX, linesY, m, n, depth - 1, False)``` Wouldn't that recursively calculate the best future move?

Comment: Yes, it's called recursively so it can try out all the moves.

Comment: What is stored in the ```evaluation``` variable?

Comment: evaluation has  [i ,j, score, is_x]. i and j are the coordinates of the move, score is the evaluation of the move and is_x tells me whether it's a horizontal or vertical move.